# Tool to create a mockup from an existing site

Tags: mockups, mockup-tool

Does someone knows a tool to help create a mockup from an existing site easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the following collections of applications:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/01/11/10-completely-free-wireframe-and-mockup-applications/
or
http://mashable.com/2012/06/07/mockup-tools/

Answer (score 0):

MockGen can generate Balsamiq and ForeUI mockups from existing web pages.

Insanely customizable output.

http://www.mockgen.com/desktop 
(I'm the developer)

Comment: link dead. any updates?

Comment: @Quamis: archive site - mockgen.xemware.com.  I've been contemplating migrating to an Electron app.

Comment: @Tim is this still supported?  Is there an Electron app now?

Comment: @KoenCornelis I can officially declare it abandoned.

Comment: Hi Tim - I was so excited to stumble upon this link, but sadly looks like the project is now gone?  Any way of still using this?

Comment: @DMcCallum83 sorry no.